# adding connection string during installation of vb.net

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, connection, connection-string, app-config

this is a follow up for my last question which is on: [adding connection string during installation of vb.net project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15682988/adding-connection-string-during-installation-of-vb-net-project?noredirect=1#comment22266321_15682988)

this is the code that I have so far but the "Configuration" in the line:

Dim config As Configuration = ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration(exePath)

has a blue line and I can't run the program because of it. I converted the C# code to that one and the blue line appears. what I'm trying to do here is to get the a string that I can use for the connection string which will be used by the app.config.

Imports System.ComponentModel

Imports System.Configuration.Install

Public Class InstallerClass

```
Public Sub New()
    MyBase.New()


    InitializeComponent()

End Sub


<RunInstaller(True)> _
Partial Public Class MyInstaller
    Inherits Installer


    Partial Public Class MyInstaller
        Inherits Installer


        Public Overrides Sub Install(ByVal stateSaver As System.Collections.IDictionary)


            MyBase.Install(stateSaver)

            Dim targetDirectory As String = Context.Parameters("targetdir")

            Dim param1 As String = Context.Parameters("Param1")

            Dim param2 As String = Context.Parameters("Param2")

            Dim param3 As String = Context.Parameters("Param3")


            Dim exePath As String = String.Format("{0}MyWindowsFormsApplication.exe", targetDirectory)

            Dim config As Configuration = ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration(exePath)

            config.AppSettings.Settings("Param1").Value = param1

            config.AppSettings.Settings("Param2").Value = param2

            config.AppSettings.Settings("Param3").Value = param3

            config.Save()

        End Sub

    End Class




End Class
```

End Class

Comment: I suggest you edit your original question with the new content.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know if this is it but some things I have noticed from the code you have posted:

- [`ConfigurationManager`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.configuration.configurationmanager%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) comes from the `System.Configuration` namespace, as does the [`Configuration`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.configuration.configuration%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) class but you don't seem to have `Imports System.Configuration` in your code (only `Imports System.Configuration.Install`)...I would try adding a `Imports System.Configuration` statement if you don't have this already
- Have you added a [reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/wkze6zky%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) to the `System.Configuration` assembly in your installer project? (Sorry, I don't remember if it comes with this assembly reference added by default)

Comment: thanks @nkvu , I added the System.Configuration assembly in the reference and the blue line disappeared. I'll try to figure out how the other things work now. thanks